# How do I fix VS code suggestion not showing?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image: screenshot link]

My VS Code suggestion doesn't show, I've already looked on youtube for solutions and restarted the app, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Youtube won't help you with such questions . That empty list probably comes from an extension that produced a suggestion list but did not populate the text field of the entries. So, check if you have an extension installed which is registered for the file type you are editing and remove it.